# Cauchy but not fast cauchy

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

As the title indicates, I am trying to find a Cauchy sequence that is not fast (or rapidly) Cauchy. Could anyone suggest something?

A sequence $\{a_n\}_{n \in \Bbb N}$is termed fast (or rapidly) Cauchy if there is a convergent series or positive numbers $\sum_{k \in \Bbb N} \epsilon_k^2$ for which

$$\|a_k - a_{k+1}\| \le \epsilon_k^2 \ \forall k $$

Comment: what do you mean by fast Cauchy?

Comment: Updated the question. I thought the term was standard that's why I did not include it the first time.

Comment: I know that the meaning is obvious, but you talk about $\epsilon_k^2$ and $e_k^2$. Besides, the exponent $2$ is unnecessary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n}$ is convergent to $0$ (and hence Cauchy) but is not fast Cauchy.